# How to hide only text value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have some code in JavaScript and Html codes This works fine(?) but the problem is textbox also disappeared.
Can anyone help?

```js
function getProductBarcode() {
    var barcode = $('#productBarcode').val();
    document.getElementById('#pos-RightTitle').style.display = 'block';
   
    $.post('functions/pos-calculation-process.php', {barcode:barcode})
        .done(function(data){
            $('#pos-RightTitle').html(data);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#productBarcode').hide();
            }, 300)
        });
    
    return false;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productBarcode"onchange = "getProductBarcode()" placeholder="Scan Barcode" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">  
</div>
```

Comment: Clarify more about your question, what you actually wants to do ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you only want to clear the text form input replace this code in `setTimeout` function:

`$('#productBarcode').hide();`

with:

```
$('#productBarcode').val('');
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this lines to avoid textbox disappear.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#productBarcode').hide();
}, 300)
```

Change your code to

```
function getProductBarcode() {
    var barcode = $('#productBarcode').val();
    document.getElementById('#pos-RightTitle').style.display = 'block';

    $.post('functions/pos-calculation-process.php', {barcode:barcode})
        .done(function(data){
            $('#pos-RightTitle').html(data);
        });

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood from your problem statement is that when you are scanning you dont want to show scanned value in field at the same time you want to change value should be there in field but should not be visible to user.

The line of code which you have written

```
 $('#productBarcode').hide();
```

Will hide the text field so you have to replace that code with given code

In css give a class

```
.hideChar {
color: white !important;
}
```

replace this

```
 $('#productBarcode').hide();
```

code with

```
$('#productBarcode').addClass('hideChar');
```

Dont forget to remove this class when you want character to be visible

```
$('#productBarcode').removeClass('hideChar')
```